# Remove line in File A if line in File B matches multiple columns in File A

Tags: perl

this is my first question asked on this site, so please excuse if I don't explain that well. I'm a novice too. I've studied some perl and unix command line stuff, but just can't work out how to solve this one.

I have 2 files - File A which is the master file with 10+ columns and approx 15,000 lines, and File B, which contains 4 columns and about 1500 lines.

I want to take each line at a time in File B, and match those columns up with the corresponding columns in File A (these are not in the same order between the two files, but the column headers are the same). If there is a match on all 4 columns of File B in File A, then remove that entire line from File A, and place into a new file (File C).

---

**Example:**

*File A*

```
individual_id   study_id.x  chromosome  g_start gene    referencel1hs   SampleFile_num  id  sample_name
54  Baillie2011 4   57497067    na  no  612 612 DonorAR2
54  Baillie2011 X   154790187   TMLHE   no  612 612 DonorAR2
54  Baillie2011 5   159351203   ADRA1B  no  612 612 DonorAR2
54  Baillie2011 13  79259801    na  no  612 612 DonorAR2
54  Baillie2011 8   4452925 CSMD1   no  610 610 DonorAH
```

*File B*

```
study_id.x  sample_name chromosome  g_start
Baillie2011 DonorAH 8   4452925
Baillie2011 DonorBC 9   5491376
Baillie2011 DonorAH 8   5829283
Baillie2011 DonorCH 8   5829283
```

---

**Result:**

*File A*

```
individual_id   study_id.x  chromosome  g_start gene    referencel1hs   SampleFile_num  id  sample_name
54  Baillie2011 4   57497067    na  no  612 612 DonorAR2
54  Baillie2011 X   154790187   TMLHE   no  612 612 DonorAR2
54  Baillie2011 5   159351203   ADRA1B  no  612 612 DonorAR2
54  Baillie2011 13  79259801    na  no  612 612 DonorAR2
```

*File C*

```
individual_id   study_id.x  chromosome  g_start gene    referencel1hs   SampleFile_num  id  sample_name
54  Baillie2011 8   4452925 CSMD1   no  610 610 DonorAH
```

Comment: If it has to be perl, is it an option to use a database? Because you reference column names it could be easier to temporarily create two tables, put the data from FileA and FileB inside, remove the datasets as described in your question and dump the result to file. Sqlite (http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_perl.htm) could be your candidate ...

Comment: ... it's also fairly straightforward in `awk` I think (at least if you don't mind using a temporary file - not many implementations support in-place editing)... I'm less familiar with `perl`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
perl -MFatal='open,close' -ali -ne '
   if ( @ARGV ) { # FileB readin
      if ( $. == 1 ) { push @names, @F;      }
      else           { push @A, join $/, @F; }
      print;
   } else { # FileA readin
      if ( $. == 1 ) {
         open FILEC, ">", "FileC.out";
         print FILEC $_;
         print;
         @remap =
            map {
               my $n = $names[$_];
               grep { $n eq $F[$_] } 0 .. $#F;
            } 0..$#names;
      } else {
         my $n = join $/, @F[@remap];
         if ( grep { $n eq $_ } @A ) { print FILEC $_; }
         else                        { print;          }
      }
   }
   eof and $. = 0;
   eof() and close FILEC;
' FileB FileA
```

---

## Explanation

- We provide the 2 files 'FileB' and 'FileA', in that order, to Perl's command line.
- During the time the FileB is being read, we do 2 things depending on whether we're at the first or some other line:

  - For the first line of FileB, we store the names of FileB fields into the array `@names`.
  - For other lines, we populate the array `@A` with the fields joined by newline `\n` provided via the `$/` which is the `RS` by default.
  - In either of these cases, we print the lines out to STDOUT so that FileB is nondestructively read in `Perl`'s `-i` mode.
- Now when we are reading the FileA, on it's first line, open a write filehandle `FILEC` in order for us to be able to fill in the `FileC.out` file.

  - We do a print to STDOUT as we want this line in FileB retained.
  - We also print to the filehandle FILEC as we want the header to go into FileC.out as well.
  - Now this is the crucial step wherein a mapping of the fields of the FileB are mapped onto the fields of FileA.
- For the non-first lines in FileA, we perform an equality check on these remapped fields with the already stored data from FileB in the array `@A`.
- In case a match is found, then write this line to FileC.out but DONOT write into FileA. In case no match is found, then we write into FileA but NOT in FileC.out.
- Upon eof of either of the files, we reset the line counter `$.` to 0 so that the first line equality checks for both the files can be performed.
- Upon final eof (detected via eof()), we close the filehandle FILEC.
- The module `Fatal.pm` is loaded with `open` and `close` functions to do an auto-exit on these operations.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. I ran the script, but it did not pull anything out of File A or put anything into File C other than the header. Any ideas? Was I supposed to alter anything in the script other than the file names at the bottom?

Comment: Ignore me! I realised in File B, I had a prefix in the entries to one of the columns. It worked perfectly, thank you so much!

Comment: I'm running into problems where it's not matching all of the entries in file B; probably because of some data mismatch between the two files. How can I adapt the script to create another file (File D), which includes a list of those not matched in File B?

Comment: @RoxaneDunbar Can you provide such a data sample where ?

Comment: This is what I'm struggling with. I would have to go through all the entries in File B and compare with File A to work out which ones were not matched and pulled into File C.

I need to adapt the script you kindly produced to add an extra bit that pulls out anything in File B that did not match in File A, into a new file (File D).

Comment: File A:
individual_id   study_id.x  chromosome  g_start gene    referencel1hs   SampleFile_num  id  sample_name
54  Baillie2011 4   57497067    na  no  612 612 DonorAR2
54  Baillie2011 X   154790187   TMLHE   no  612 612 DonorAR2
54  Baillie2011 5   159351203   ADRA1B  no  612 612 DonorAR2
54  Baillie2011 13  79259801    na  no  612 612 DonorAR2
54  Baillie2011 8   4452925 CSMD1   no  610 610 DonorAH

File B:
study_id.x  sample_name chromosome  g_start
Baillie2011 DonorAH 8   4452925
Baillie2011 DonorBC 9   5491376
Baillie2011 DonorAH 8   5829283
Baillie2011 DonorCH 8   5829283

Comment: becomes:
File A:
individual_id   study_id.x  chromosome  g_start gene    referencel1hs   SampleFile_num  id  sample_name 
54  Baillie2011 4   57497067    na  no  612 612 DonorAR2
54  Baillie2011 X   154790187   TMLHE   no  612 612 DonorAR2
54  Baillie2011 5   159351203   ADRA1B  no  612 612 DonorAR2
54  Baillie2011 13  79259801    na  no  612 612 DonorAR2

Comment: File C:
individual_id   study_id.x  chromosome  g_start gene    referencel1hs   SampleFile_num  id  sample_name
54  Baillie2011 8   4452925 CSMD1   no  610 610 DonorAH

File D:

study_id.x  sample_name chromosome  g_start
Baillie2011 DonorBC 9   5491376
Baillie2011 DonorAH 8   5829283
Baillie2011 DonorCH 8   5829283

Comment: @RoxaneDunbar Can you raise a new question for this requirement as this forces a complete rewrite of what's given above. Neither can I give it in this comments section since it's now it's even larger.

Comment: Thank you :)

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/385191/remove-line-in-file-a-if-line-in-file-b-matches-multiple-columns-in-file-a-plac