# Remove line in File A if line in File B matches multiple columns in File A, place matched lines in File C, and unmatched lines in File D

Tags: text-processing, grep, perl

I have 2 files - **File A** which is the master file with 10+ columns and approx 15,000 lines, and **File B**, which contains 4 columns and about 1500 lines.

I want to take each line at a time in **File B**, and match those columns up with the corresponding columns in **File A** (these are not in the same order between the two files, but the column headers are the same). If there is a match on all 4 columns of **File B** in **File A**, then remove that entire line from **File A**, and place into a new file (**File C**).

I also need any unmatched lines in **File B** to be placed into a new file (**File D**).

**Example:**

File A:

```
individual_id   study_id.x  chromosome  g_start gene    referencel1hs   SampleFile_num  id  sample_name
54  Baillie2011 4   57497067    na  no  612 612 DonorAR2
54  Baillie2011 X   154790187   TMLHE   no  612 612 DonorAR2
54  Baillie2011 5   159351203   ADRA1B  no  612 612 DonorAR2
54  Baillie2011 13  79259801    na  no  612 612 DonorAR2
54  Baillie2011 8   4452925 CSMD1   no  610 610 DonorAH
```

File B:

```
study_id.x  sample_name chromosome  g_start
Baillie2011 DonorAH 8   4452925
Baillie2011 DonorBC 9   5491376
Baillie2011 DonorAH 8   5829283
Baillie2011 DonorCH 8   5829283
```

**Result:**

File A:

```
individual_id   study_id.x  chromosome  g_start gene    referencel1hs   SampleFile_num  id  sample_name
54  Baillie2011 4   57497067    na  no  612 612 DonorAR2
54  Baillie2011 X   154790187   TMLHE   no  612 612 DonorAR2
54  Baillie2011 5   159351203   ADRA1B  no  612 612 DonorAR2
54  Baillie2011 13  79259801    na  no  612 612 DonorAR2
```

File C:

```
individual_id   study_id.x  chromosome  g_start gene    referencel1hs   SampleFile_num  id  sample_name
54  Baillie2011 8   4452925 CSMD1   no  610 610 DonorAH
```

File D:

```
study_id.x sample_name chromosome g_start
Baillie2011 DonorBC 9 5491376 
Baillie2011 DonorAH 8 5829283 
Baillie2011 DonorCH 8 5829283
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
perl -MFatal='open,close' -ali -ne '
   BEGIN{
      open FILEC, ">", "FileC.out";
      open FILED, ">", "FileD.out";
   }

   if ( @ARGV ) { # FileB readin
      if ( $. == 1 ) {
         push @names, @F;
         print FILED $_;
      } else {
         push @A, join $/, @F;
         push @B, $_;
      }
      print;
   } else { # FileA readin
      if ( $. == 1 ) {
         print FILEC $_;
         print;
         @remap =
            map {
               my $n = $names[$_];
               grep { $n eq $F[$_] } 0 .. $#F;
            } 0..$#names;
      } else {
         my $n = join $/, @F[@remap];
         if ( my($id) = grep { $n eq $A[$_] } 0 .. $#A ) {
            push @IDs, $id;
            print FILEC $_;
         } else {
            print;
         }
      }
   }

   eof and $. = 0;

   END{
      splice(@B, $_, 1) for @IDs;
      @B and print FILED $_ for @B;
      close $_ for *FILEC, *FILED;
   }
' FileB FileA
```

After this the files "FileC.out" FileD.out are created. FileA is modified and FileB remains unaltered.

The flow is just as it was in your earlier query, the filed processing has been added.

Comment: Perfect, thank you.

I also have a similar task to complete, but the numbers in 1 particular column between File A and File B are out by up to 200. Is there a way to put in a discretionary window of 200, so a match can be made if it is either 200 less or 200 more? This only needs to be applied to 1 column.

Comment: @RoxaneDunbar Again, you would need to raise a new question for this. And put the sample data input/expected output files FileA/B/C/D etc. on the `https://pastebin.com`  website.

Answer (score 1):

Use an awk script as below:

```
NR == FNR {
        strt=1
        }
NR != 1 && FNR ==1 {
        strt=0
        }
strt == 1 {
        fileB[FNR"_"$1$2$3$4]=$0
        }
strt == 0 {
        fileA[$2$9$3$4]=$0
        }
END {
        for (i in fileB) {
                split(i,arry,"_")
                if (fileA[arry[2]] != "") {
                                print fileA[arry[2]] > "fileC"
                                system("sed -i \"/"fileA[arry[2]]"/d\" 
fileA") 
                }
                else {
                                 print fileB[i] > "fileD"
                }
        }
```

We first read the lines from each file into two arrays, fileA and fileB and both have the same key i.e. "Baillie2011DonorAH84452925" We loop through each entry in the fileB array and check for a corresponding entry in fileA. If it exists, add the entry to fileC through a print redirect and also action a sed command through awk's system function (BEWARE - the system function carries code injection risk and so assess the risk accordingly) If there is no match, output the line to fileD.

Action with:

```
awk -f awkscriptfile fileB fileA
```

Answer (score 1):

**Usage:** `./processing.sh`

This script doesn't change the original `file_A`, but create the `new_file_A`. You can add couple lines of code to it, for removing the original `file_A` and renaming the `new_file_A` to the `file_A`. I can add comments to the code, if it does, what you want.

```
#!/bin/bash

file_a="file_A.txt"
file_b="file_B.txt"
file_c="file_C.txt"
file_d="file_D.txt"

print_to_files () {
    awk -v lines="$1" -v outfile1="$3" -v outfile2="$4" '
        BEGIN {
            cnt = 2;
            split(lines,lines_arr);
        }

        {
            if (NR == 1) {
                print $0 > outfile1;
                print $0 > outfile2;
            } else if (NR == lines_arr[cnt]) {
                print $0 >> outfile1;
                cnt++;
            } else {
                print $0 >> outfile2;   
            }
        }
    ' "$2"
}

lines_matching () {
    grep -n -f <(echo "$1") <(echo "$2") | cut -d ':' -f 1
}

file_a_cols=$(awk '{printf "%s %s %s %s\n", $2, $9, $3, $4; }' "$file_a")
file_b_cols=$(tr -s ' ' < "$file_b")

matched_lines_file_a=$(lines_matching "$file_b_cols" "$file_a_cols")
matched_lines_file_b=$(lines_matching "$file_a_cols" "$file_b_cols")

print_to_files "$matched_lines_file_a" "$file_a" "$file_c" "new_$file_a"

print_to_files "$matched_lines_file_b" "$file_b" "/dev/null" "$file_d"
```